# Unable to display Image on jLabel from SQL Sever 2008

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to get an image from SQL server 2008 using JAVA Netbeans.

My `SQL` data type is `varchar(max)` and inserted value = [B@ada3d6

My code is:

```
byte[] imagedata=rs.getBytes("Doc_Photo");
format=new ImageIcon(imagedata);
Image mm=format.getImage();
Image img2=mm.getScaledInstance(jLabel22.getWidth(), jLabel22.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(img2);enter code here
jLabel22.setIcon(image);'
```

Comment: there are no error found but image not displaying in label

Comment: Why are you storing an image in a `varchar`? Surely you're using a `varbinary`, or are you storing the reletive path in the table? If so, it should probably be an `nvarchar` and doesn't need to be of length `MAX`. 300 characters would be more than enough (I believe the longest a file path can be in windows is about 256 characters).